# Running Wire to Electrical Panel Box

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I have to run approximately 8-10 home Romex (14/2 and 12/2) wires to Electric panel box.

So, Can I run those wires to the panel box as per the picture, Is this sound ok ?

Is there any limit, I can group maximum no. of wires together ?

**More Details** : The wires have to run for 10 feet along the joist. so I am planning to run and staple wires parallel to cable wires ( green & black) and run the wires through a 2 inches of hole (1-2 feet away from panel box) and finally pull the wires through behind joists to run into the panel box.
I'll be using wire tie to group them together.[image]

Thank you so much in advance.

Thanks

I know I have to group them together. any maximum limit for grouping ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slow down on the hole size, unless using a conduit nipple the inspector will usually call more than 2 cables through a hole bundling (where 2 or more cables are run without spacing) so a massive hole for 8-10 ea 12 or 14 gauge cables just won’t work.
Next more than 3 current carrying conductors will require derating.

Drilling a series of 3/8 -3/4 holes is a better idea for most diy. inspectors don’t allow the proper derating of NM wire and it is easier just to limit the number of cables.

I have won the arguments in the past and even used bushings through a beam to prove the point (a nipple under 24” you don’t have to derate and you can run more)

As for running the wires there are 1 or 2 cable staples 2 cable are longer. Next there are wire stacking “staples” actually a nail that has spaced clips to run the wires along the studs. The cables need to be 1-1/4” back from the face of the studs and above the ceiling joist 1-1/4”

Comment: I thought the derate was for wires in conduit....  thanks Ed.....  I'm basically a conduit guy. +1

Comment: What about when you have a bunch of cables going into the center hub of a panel?  Do they have to be derated?

Comment: @Ed Beal, if you look at the existing wires running in a group to the panel box, there are more than 8-10 wires are group together. May be, Its depend on local city count. ?

Comment: In my neck of the woods, 3 cables per hole is what's allowed (4 if you have an easy going inspector), regardless of hole size, which seems silly to me, but it is what it is. So lots of smaller holes are better.  Ed Beal, who has a lot more experience than me got it totally right. +1   I also like the the use of stacking clips to separate the cables.   Just used a lot of them when I wired my son's new build and the inspector had no issue with them.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Three per hole does seem silly.

Comment: @JACK  Yep!  But I, not being a professional electrician, I hired an electrician to do a "pre-inspection" and point out anything I'd missed or messed up on on my son's house. He didn't find much other than, " You've got 6 cables going thru those 1 1/2" holes and the inspector probably will call you out on that. Wasn't a hard fix, basically drilling additional holes closer to the fixture/switch/outlet boxes, and moving a few cables to the new holes. Still, I agree, it's a stupid requirement.  I can see not stuffing 10 cables into a 1 1/2" hole, but 5 or 6? what's the issue?

Comment: Vicky I am a professional electrician you can check out NEC 310.15.B.3.A for the derating schedule. (NEC means national electric code) a 24” conduit nipple or shorter has an exemption bored holes through wood do not. 4 cables 2 current carrying conductors is the maximum even with derating. Go for it but just note that the inspector may hit you for bundling over 2 cables. Some inspectors are real jerks to DIY folks I have been called to fix things that were opinion, if I installed ti would pass. An example when I moved to my current county I had not worked here and did a diy panel upgrade  cont

Comment: Cont : I pulled the permit as a homeowner The inspector was going to fail the install on multiple “shortcomings” I asked what they were and the code reference as I went to grab my handbook, turns out the short comings were not code but what he liked to see. The job was signed off in short I had heard of things like this on jobs I was called in to clean up. Most had something like a bunch of cable through a big hole, fencing staples to secure romex or nmb, switched neutral, and a host of other things I can’t even list all the reasons like these I have seen, reinspections get expensive fast.

Comment: So I am thinking to use multi cable staples, I can run 4 wires in one multi cable staple. So can I create a one 1+ inch of hole to pull the 4 wires into the panel box, right ? I have to do the same for rest of the 4 wires.

Comment: Vicky according to code and the derating table you can go to 3 but I got so tired of battling it out I usually only run 2 through bored holes.  Be ready to tell the the inspector that the cables have been derate for 6 current carrying conductors per 310.15.B.A  , this allows full use of both 15 & 20 amp circuits because the derate factor is 80% and all components must be rated @ 75 degrees, going to 7-9 conductors requires derating of 70%. Why not use the 90 degree table al allowed by code? All components have to be rated for 90 to use this derate. Most panels are only 75 deg rated. 3 max ok

Comment: Thanks Ed Beal. I'll only run 2 through a hole. How close the hole can be drill to each others ?  I would have to drill at least 5 holes of 3/4 or 3/8 5 inch to run 2 wires in each.

Comment: The holes can be touching but I usually offset them when I have room in a zigzag staying more than 1-1/4 away from the face or edge you have a lot of room stay closer to the center.

Comment: Thanks Ed Beal, One last question, I don't see space to staple the wire out side of box. I have to staple 2 wires together with-in 12 inch, right . How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you not able to staple because of trying to go in the side and you don’t have space to drive the staple? In those cases I go down on the other side of the stud next to the box. The wire path is staple through the stud, clamp in the box, I use “insiders” a plastic snap in from the inside of the box clamp they are the best for things like this where 2 screw clamps are difficult to access. Raco insider, Romex clamp will bring them up on line. I have no affiliation with the company, I started using these on remodels and before long for everything because of there ease of use.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding a new answer instead of editing as my original answer still is my recommendation since I don’t know your local AHJ.  The 2020 code has updates on MC/AC bundling, with focus in 1 area of code usually other methods are also more closely examined at the professional level and DIY more so.

Code allows cables to be run together but because of inductive heating there are penalties that reduce the ampacity of the wires (in cables or not)

We use table 310.15.B.16 for most residential wiring the use of this table is limited to not more than 3 current carrying conductors.

Code requires small wires current to be limited per 240.4.D

However these above requirements have minor exceptions, with exceptions come exclusions and additional requirements.

Table 310.15.B.3.A  adjustment factors (commonly called derate) the code covering these covers many pages. And several code articles.

Derating is allowed in residential but the wiring and components must be listed for use with the higher temp tables 75 or 90. And you can not exceed the maximum current rating for small wires 15,20 & 30 for 14,12 &10 awg wire.

Now most equipment is rated for 75 deg so a quick calculation of 15 amp for a 14 awg branch circuit on 75deg  or 20a x .8 = 16a so that will work so 4-6 conductors is fine.
Going to 90 degree table the switches, receptacles and load center (breaker panel have to be 90 degree rated). unless commercial equipment is used a residential 15 amp circuit is limited to 3 cables or 6 current carrying conductors. Why not use the 7-9 conductors with the 70% derate .7 x 20= 14 amps so the OCPD (breaker) would have to be smaller than 14 amps.

Ok now for 12awg wire or cables the same rules apply 4-6current. carrying conductors using the 75 deg table for 12awg is 25a x .8 = 20 amps

In both the 12 & 14 awg methods you can see if we could use the 90 degree table that would allow another 5 amps on each wire size and the insulation can handle this load, yes there are load centers out there 90 degree rated and most motor loads (like attic fans and circulation fans are 90deg rated and could use this method) but most residential components are only rated to 75 deg and the inspector will flag more than 6 CCC through a bored hole.

If you really want to go more than 3 use a short conduit nipple less than 24” with bushings on each end then you can have a max fill rate of 60% and No derating is required. This is how we make it down the wall with a 2” or 2-1/2” pipe into the load center with many cables. Remember to calculate the area of a flat cable the width is used.

There is an additional method to do use the 90 degree table but unless a specialty home with many pumps and fans it is really outside DIY as I said I have battled this one with inspectors, and for a few extra holes it’s just not worth it so a short nipple with bushings although expensive may be the best method with limited space. But in this case I see no reason to have more than 2 cables if wanted go to 3 but unless all components are 90 degree rated the inspector can flag the job requiring an extra inspection.
Once you upset an inspector be prepared for them to take out a “magnifying glass” and try to find something else. Note some of my inspectors are also structural inspectors if they feel you are trying to cheat the code they will find things.